# How do I name my list with having space in between two words?

Tags: python, list, pycharm

I am new to programming and I am facing an issue with naming my list(srry I don't know what it is called in a programming language).
So when I use

```
    roll no=[1,2,3,4]
```

It is giving me syntax error: invalid syntax 
(red mark between roll and no) :(

So is there any way to add space in name of my list

I apologize if I am being dumb. Thnx for you help :)

Comment: You are most definitely NOT dumb. Everyone starts somewhere! Keep coding! :)

Answer (score 2):

Variable names cannot have a space, you'd need to use the following:

```
roll_no=[1,2,3,4]
```